# I dont seem to find a refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am not very familiar with OAuth and Google API so please bear with me.
I am trying to refresh my token. I'm a not too familiar with **Access Tokens** and **Refresh Tokens**

this is my client set up

```
$this->client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$this->client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$this->client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$this->client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT);
$this->client->setAccessType($ACCESSTYPE);
$this->client->setApplicationName($APPNAME);
$this->client->setAccessType('offline');
```

this is my condition

```
if($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

        // $this->client->authenticate();

        $NewAccessToken = json_decode($this->client->getAccessToken());

        $this->client->refreshToken($NewAccessToken->refresh_token);
    }
```

I did

```
var_dump($NewAccessToken);
```

and this is what it returned:

```
object(stdClass)[35]
public 'access_token' => string 'ya29.fgGjd2aJaqOtF_0xp6alhLo9SWSe97JPhmSHNb7E1LIwvEQFjJWQM2MFulVryKLu3y_AFymxE953Q' (length=83)
public 'token_type' => string 'Bearer' (length=6)
public 'expires_in' => int 3600
public 'created' => int 1432520695
```

no trace of **refresh_token**.

Comment: revoke the access first, then try again, you will see that refresh_token will be there. Make sure also that the `setAccessType` is set to "offline"

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer, forgot to re-authenticate the client object along with setAccessType = 'offline';